# How to encrypt data in sqlite database?

Tags: jquery, sqlite, encryption, cordova

I am looking for an  data encryption library in jquery(or javascript) for sqlite database as I am working in phonegap so I need a library that should wok for **android,blackberry** and **iphone** as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) is a Javascript library that implements numerous standard encryption algorithms.

If you're looking for a lightweight algorithm, there's a JS implementation of Tiny Encrpytion Algorithm (TEA) towards the bottom of [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/tea-block.html).

Both are pure JS so should work across platforms within a Phonegap application.

Comment: Note that TEA (and its variants) are cryptographically broken and nowhere near secure.

Answer (score 1):

Try SJCL, which is compatible with JavaScript and best for cross platform apps:

http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/